# Excel formula help -- sum numbers that meet a certain criteria

Tags: excel, formula

I want to add all of the %LU*AEI numbers that have the same UID (see screenshot). I thought about using an IF formula but my UID ranges from W1-W200 so the formula would be cumbersome.

I also don't know how I would add the numbers together to get one number per UID. My thoughts keep straying towards something object-based because I work in Python and R frequently, but I don't think there's a way to funnel numbers into an object in Excel.

Does anyone even have any hints at how to begin approaching this?

I have tried `=SUMIF(C2:C3, A3=A2)`, `=SUMIF(C2:C3,A3=A2, C3:C2)` both of which did not work.

[image]

Comment: Why not `SumIf()` or `SumIfs()`?  What formulas have you attempted? Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: What would your desired output look like?  There are many ways to do this using, as @BruceWayne suggested, SUMIF()/SUMIFS().

Comment: I started to do an `IF` formula that fell apart pretty quickly. I'll try a `SUMIF()` and get back to you.

Comment: @ScottCraner --  My ideal output would be one number for each UID (W1-W200)

Comment: Try `=SUMIF(A:A, A2, C:C)`

Comment: @Jeeped Holy cow that was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: A pivot table would do this.

Comment: @Jeeped Could you explain what you did? I am very appreciative that you provided me with that formula, but I would also like to know exactly how/why it works. I feel like I'll learn something that way.

Comment: Both the [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B) and [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-C9E748F5-7EA7-455D-9406-611CEBCE642B) are adequately explained in official documentation and each comes with a video demonstrating the operation. I cannot really provide anything that is not covered there but I will remark that I typically use SUMIFS for everything whether there is a single condition or multiple ones. I find it easier to use the one-size-fits-all SUMIFS in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

In a new sheet, in column A stick:

```
W1
W2
W3
W...
```

Down to `W200` then in B1 of that new sheet:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,A1, Sheet1!$C:$C)
```

And copy that down. You could also do it all in one formula, where in a new sheet you put in A1:

```
=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A, "W" & ROW() , Sheet1!$C:$C)
```

And copy that down. That will just make a `W1`, `W2` value based on the row that the formula is in and then do the `SUMIF()` based on that value.